# rust nalgebra, how to modify a matrix block?

Tags: math, rust, linear-algebra, nalgebra

I am using nalgebra and trying to do the following:

Given a large dense amtrix, e.g. a 5x5. I want to grab a block of that matrix, e.e.g a 4x5 sublock, and treat that block as a matrix. I want to perform scalar multiplication and vector addition on the block and I want the result to reflect in the original matrix without performing copies.

For example:

```rust
let mat /*
initialize mat to:
┌                                                         ┐
  │    -1.9582069 -0.0063802134   -0.40666944     -23.94156 │
  │   -0.39497808   -0.44723305      1.908919    -16.907166 │
  │   -0.09702926     1.9493433    0.43662617    -11.965615 │
  │             0             0            -0             2 │
  └                                                         ┘
*/

let mut slice = &mat.slice((0, 0), (3, 4));
slice = slice * 0;
```

Should make it so that if I print `mat` now the top 3 rows are zeroed out.

I have tried different combinations of parameters but I have not quite been able to get the result I want.

Currently all my attempts end in errors like this:

```rust
39 |             *slice = 0.0 * slice;
   |             ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `SliceStorageMut`, found struct `VecStorage`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unable to write through an immutable slice like the one produced by `slice` so you need to take a mutable slice of the matrix using `slice_mut`. You also don't need the `&` since the slice object is already a reference in itself. If you take an immutable reference to a mutable slice, it will prevent you from writing to the matrix.

```rust
// Take a slice of the matrix
let mut slice = mat.slice_mut((0, 0), (3, 4));
// Modify the slice in place
slice *= 2.0;
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5a1e246f320e67701c7a16907c5e9ab)